# Problem with variable in jQuery (undefined) even when I check if it exist

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, local-storage

Here is my code where if got a problem with:

```
// WORKS
    var cart;
    var productlist = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
// But if localStorage is empty go an error "productlist = undefined
// This was the solution, where I'm thinking about, but without success
    if (typeof productlist !== "undefined") {
        var productlist = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
    }else{
        var productlist = [];
    }

    $('#addtocard').on('click', function(e) {

        $('#bill-table > tbody > tr').each(function() {

            if(product === undefined) {
                var product = {};
            }

            product.naam = $(this).children('.naam').html();
            product.type = $(this).data('type');
            product.id = $(this).data('productid');

            productlist.push(product);
        });

        console.log('--------------');
        console.log('ProductList:'+JSON.stringify(productlist));
        console.log('LocalStorage:'+localStorage.getItem('cart'));

        localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(productlist));
        $('#json_producten').val(JSON.stringify(productlist));

        e.preventDefault();
    });

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $('#json_producten').val(localStorage.getItem('cart'));

    console.log('--------------');
    console.log('ProductList:'+JSON.stringify(productlist));
    console.log('LocalStorage:'+localStorage.getItem('cart'));
```

Which part works: If you put a single product to the cart, there is no problem. If you put one item twice in the cart no problem. Then return's both products in one array.

The problem is if you put Product one in the cart, than you go to an other page an the hidden input field "#json_producten" show the correct cart (product one is inside) but if you press addtocard btn on product 2 her overruled the current cart.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Not able to get what issue you are having and where? Also not sure what does "_on product 2 her overruled the current cart_" means.

Comment: If you start with Product A and put this in the cart its oke, if you put product A two times in cart there is not problem. The value of #json_producten is Product A two times. But the problem is it you put Product A in the cart than navigate to Product B and put this in the cart, than the Product A (two times) is gone and only product B is in the cart. Hope you know what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
if (typeof productlist !== "undefined") {
    var productlist = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
}else{
    var productlist = [];
}
```

To:

```
if(localStorage.getItem('cart') == null){
    productlist = [];
}else{
    productlist = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
}
```

This is the solution, but if there is an better way let me know!

Comment: `var productlist = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart') || '[]')` for a one liner

Comment: `var productlist = [];
if (localStorage.getItem('cart')) {
  productlist = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
}`